# Visual Studio: COMException opening project file

Tags: visual-studio

I am using VS 2008. When I opened a c# project file created by another developer I received a System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException. I searched the web and found the solution was to comment out the ProjectExtensions section of the project file. I did this an it opened fine. But looking over the commented code I don't understand what would cause this. Does anyone have a clue why this would fail on my local machine? I have IIS 7 installed and running properly.

```
  <ProjectExtensions>
    <VisualStudio>
      <FlavorProperties GUID="{349c5851-65df-11da-9384-00065b846f21}">
        <WebProjectProperties>
          <UseIIS>True</UseIIS>
          <AutoAssignPort>True</AutoAssignPort>
          <DevelopmentServerPort>62088</DevelopmentServerPort>
          <DevelopmentServerVPath>/</DevelopmentServerVPath>
          <IISUrl>http://localhost/</IISUrl>
          <NTLMAuthentication>False</NTLMAuthentication>
          <UseCustomServer>False</UseCustomServer>
          <CustomServerUrl>
          </CustomServerUrl>
          <SaveServerSettingsInUserFile>False</SaveServerSettingsInUserFile>
        </WebProjectProperties>
      </FlavorProperties>
    </VisualStudio>
  </ProjectExtensions>
```

Comment: Okay I found the reason(s):
1. I was not running VS 08 as administrator
2. I already had a site mapped to http://localhost so it could not create it on starting the project

Solution? Edit the project file in notepad and change the IISUrl value to http://localhost/sitename

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Okay I found the reason(s):

1. I was not running VS 08 as administrator.
2. I already had a site mapped to localhost so it could not create it on starting the project Solution? Edit the project file in notepad and change the IISUrl value to localhost/sitename

Comment: Had this issue working on a service built using 2008, only it prevented the project from opening whether or not I was in administrator mode.  I removed the IISUrl line node (it was already pointing to localhost/sitename) and it opened fine

Comment: was for me too, after a hours of investigation, your comment solves my trouble

Answer (score 13):

Following solution worked for me just now..

> - Once the solution opens, right-click on the unavailable project and select - - Edit project_file_name.vbproj.
> - Scroll to the bottom of the page, and delete the `ProjectExtensions` section.
> - Save the page.
> - Right-click again on the unavailable project, and select Reload Project.

Your project should now be available and you should be able to see all your project files.

Comment: You're my today-day-saver ;)

Answer (score 2):

Also on XP make sure the following are checked under Add/Remove Programs -> Add/Remove Windows Components:

```
Internet Information Services Manager
Background Intelligent Transfer Services (BITS) Server Extensions
Common Files
World Wide Web Service
```

([Credit](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/rsysarch/v11/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.sa.saxt.install.guide.doc/topics/t_install_IIS_Windows.html))

Answer (score 0):

I got this error on last two days ago.
I can open the IIS 6 in window feature of control panel and install in your laptop.
After that please restart our laptop and try again.
I can successfully open our project.
We are using VS 2008 .U can take a look my reference pic.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CVfpU.png)